# javascript pass table data to php script

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table (that can be fairly large....say 200x200 px) where each cell has a background color, and a small image in it. The user will be able to click the cell and change the color/symbol (the symbol represents the color), via jQuery/Javascript. How can I pass the table data to a PHP script so it can be assembled into an image or pdf?

Comment: This is much too broad. What part of doing this are you asking about?

Comment: This question is way too generic. You need to attempt it yourself and come back with specific questions with code examples when you run into a problem.

Comment: It may be vague, but it illustrates the point. You will need to pass the table cells' properties to the PHP script, Ajax possibly.

Comment: I'd convert your table into json, send that to your php then use php to recreate the image from the data. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. Sometime I know what I am asking and ask it in the wrong fashion. I was asking how to get the data from the table. I have the table and cells made, I just couldn't get started gathering the cell data to send to php.

Comment: I tend to give too much info sometimes..seems fairly straight forward when condensed down to the question. How can I pass the table data to a PHP script? Kinda like everyone jumped on the bandwagon as it passed by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var output = [],
    row    = 0;
$('table').find('tr').each(function (index, obj) {
    output.push([]);
    var TDs = $(this).children();
    $.each(TDs, function (i, o) {
        output[row].push($(this).css('background-color'));
    });
    row++;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y8NwV/

This will iterate through each `TD` element in your table, get it's background color, and then add that data to a two dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I needed. How to get the data from the table.